# Is there a Webm C#/Xaml controll for UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Is there any standard inbuilt control(like the Mediaplayer) in the new UWP SDK for Webm?
Android supports it AFAIK, so shouldn´t the UWP SDK support it to port Android apps onto Windows Phone? 
If there are no standart controls, is there any other way to play Webm?
I dont want to use a Webviev to Play Webm videos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WinRT does not support WebM by default.

But, microsoft posted an article 'Using FFMpeg in Windows Applications'. As of this, you can use ffmpeg as MediaStreamSource.

[Using FFMpeg in Windows Applications](http://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/06/05/using-ffmpeg-in-windows-applications/)

And, FFMpeg supports WEBM. Maybe, UWP should be able to play WEBM by using FFMpeg.

(But I haven't tried yet by myself. because the build proc is complicated...)

[Compile and Use FFmpeg Libraries for Windows Runtime (Windows 10 or Windows 8.1 Apps)](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT)

Comment: Note - Initial version of FFmpegInterop have some issues about WebM playing, but the recent (2017) one is good. You can play many of WebM.